# Using a variable property inside msg

Tags: jsf, el

So I am working on an app and I have it set up so the following line

```
<h:outputText value = "#{msg['properties.help.keys.example.text']}" />
```

Will print some output value from a properties file. What I want is to make part of that string it uses to find the properties variable.

I.E.

```
 <h:outputText value = "#{msg['properties.help.keys.' + cc.attrs.key + '.text']}" />
```

Where cc.attrs.key is a value I pass into the xhtml. Is this possible if so how do you do it?

Comment: Did you try this?  What didn't work about it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't concatenate strings in EL expressions like that. The `+` is in EL exclusively a sum operator for numbers. You need to use `<c:set>` to concatenate strings with EL expressions before nesting it in another EL expression. Concatenating the string is then solely be done by just inlining the expression.

```
<c:set var="key" value="properties.help.keys.#{cc.attrs.key}.text" />
<h:outputText value="#{msg[key]}" />
```

<strike>In the upcoming EL 3.0, there will be a [new EL operator `&`](http://java.net/projects/el-spec/pages/Operators) for concatenating strings in EL expressions. The use of the `&` character as operator is however discutable in XML based view technologies as it's a reserved XML character, I've been in discussion with EL guys about that. It should be possible with an alternative operator like `ct` which is in line with `gt`, `lt`, etc.</strike>

---

**Update**: in EL 3.0, there is the new EL operator `+=` for concatenating strings in EL expressions. Your use case can then be solved as follows:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['properties.help.keys' += cc.attrs.key += '.text']}" />
```

Comment: Wow that was super fast, this answer was literally up there by the time the page loaded after I clicked submit (real slow internet here)thanx